# Rails - Authlogic: undefined method 'valid_password?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I managed to get user account creation working however I am running into an issue when I try to log in to the newly created account:

> undefined method `valid_password?'

and the error highlights

```
if @user_session.save!
```

I am Authlogic and BCrypt on Rails 5 and I do not know why or how to fix the error above. I used [this guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/rails-authentication-with-authlogic/) in order to setup Authlogic and I am able to sign out but when trying to log in, I get the above error. From some searches, some people have been able to solve this by [restarting Heroku](https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm/issues/67) but I am not using Heroku so I do not believe that would work for me. Another solution was to [add some password fields](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/189369) but I believe the "has_secure_password" would supply those fields accordingly. Does anyone know why this error occurs and/or how to fix it? Thanks!

Users Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :activities
  has_secure_password

    validates :first_name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 1}
    validates :last_name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 1}
    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {minimum: 5}
    validates :password_digest, length: {minimum: 6}
    validates :password, :confirmation => true, length: {minimum: 4}
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

    #-----------------------New Stuff ---------------------------------------
    acts_as_authentic do |c|
      c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::BCrypt
    end

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------Unsure if working--------------
    #validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
    #validates_presence_of :email
    #validates_uniqueness_of :email
    #----------------------------------------------

    def self.authenticate(email, password)
      user = find_by_email(email)
      if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
        user
      else
        nil
      end
    end

    def encrypt_password
      if password.present?
        self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
      end
    end
  end
```

User Sessions Controller:

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(user_session_params)
    if @user_session.save!
      flash[:success] = 'Welcome back'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    flash[:success] = 'Goodbye'
    #redirect_to root_path - Should redirect somewhere after logout
  end

  private

  def user_session_params
    params.require(:user_session).permit(:email,:password)
  end

end
```

Current User and User Session Tables:

```
  create_table "user_sessions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  end
```

**EDIT 04-11-17**
After making the changes below, it worked for me and I was able to log out and in without the mentioned problems. I still do not know why it gave me the error but I suspect it is because I was using "has_secure_password" which does not have a function to check if the password is valid ("valid_password?").

Answer (score 0):

Alright turns out I managed to fix it by removing "has_secure_password" and just solely relying on "acts_as_authentic". After that, I was able to log in successfully. Here's my updated code:

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :activities
  acts_as_authentic

    validates :first_name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 1}
    validates :last_name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 1}
    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {minimum: 5}
    validates :password, :confirmation => true, length: {minimum: 4}
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

    #-----------------------New Stuff ---------------------------------------


    #------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------Unsure if working--------------
    #validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
    #validates_presence_of :email
    #validates_uniqueness_of :email
    #----------------------------------------------

    def self.authenticate(email, password)
      user = find_by_email(email)
      if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
        user
      else
        nil
      end
    end

    def encrypt_password
      if password.present?
        self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
      end
    end
  end
```

User Table:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "crypted_password",  null: false
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  end
```

Not all of the fields above are required but I have them as I'm still new to Rails. The main thing required was "crypted_password" and "password_salt". After making the above edits, I was able to log in and out successfully without the mentioned error.